# Why isn't my regex_validator working in formset without overriding clean method?

Tags: python, django, forms

### My goal

The following code  is supposed to display a **formset** containing a certain number of **TravellerForm** then validate them and save the **CompleteSubscription** and his **Traveller** associated.

Only the main contact - first form - is supposed to have a mendatory phone number at the E.164 format validated by a regex.

### Results of the following code

It correctly suppress the phone number field for other forms than the first and *properly displays the fields I need*.

Then, when I submit my form , the travellers are saved in my database, **including the first although I put an invalid phone number in it**. The subscription is correctly saved.

For fix this issue, I've overrided the clean_phone_number method, it seems working but it's giving me two errors and not only one as expected.

- **Phone number must be in E.164 format. Ex: +33123456789**
- **Make sure that this value has a maximum of 16 characters (currently 143).**

### My problematic

Why does I need to override the clean_phone_number method to display the errors, aren't formsets supposed to call the clean method of theirs forms before saving ?

If it so, why is my clean_phone_number method called when I override it ?

I'm by the way interesting to know how could django count 143 character when I actually entered only 12 characters (I guess the deletion of a field could have destroyed a bit the count).

### The code itself

There is the template,

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    {{  form.as_p }}
    </br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

The view,

```
def set_main_form(formset):
    is_main = True
    for form in formset:
        if is_main:
            is_main = False
        else:
            del form.fields['phone_number']

# Main contact is the first Travelller
def complete_subscription_create(request, base_pk):
    base = BaseSubscription.objects.get(pk=base_pk)
    number_forms = base.nb_adults + base.nb_children + base.nb_babies

    TravellerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Traveller, form=TravellerForm,
                                            extra=number_forms)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TravellerFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        set_main_form(formset)
        if formset.is_valid():
            base = BaseSubscription.objects.get(pk=base_pk)
            subscription = CompleteSubscription(base_subscription=base)
            subscription.save()
            formset[0].instance.is_main_contact = True
            for form in formset:
                form.instance.subscription = subscription
            formset.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        formset = TravellerFormSet()
        set_main_form(formset)
    return render(request, 'offerspace/completesubscription_form.html',
                  {'formset': formset})
```

The forms instanciated in the formset,

```
class TravellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Traveller
        fields = ('first_name', 'second_name', 'last_name',
                  'passport_country', 'phone_number')

    # For some reasons, the regex validator works when I uncomment this
    #def clean_phone_number(self):
        #cleaned_data = super(TravellerForm, self).clean()
        #return cleaned_data
```

The model of the TravellerForm

```
class Traveller(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    # This field is in E.164 Format, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164
    # for  more informations about this format
    phone_error_message = """
        Phone number must be in E.164 format.
        Ex: +33123456789
        """
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{8,15}$',
                                 message=phone_error_message,
                                 code='invalid_phone_number')
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True,
                                    max_length=16)
    passport_country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    is_main_contact = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(CompleteSubscription)
```

And the CompleteSubscription model instanciated in the view,

```
class CompleteSubscription(models.Model):
    base_subscription = models.OneToOneField(BaseSubscription)
    final_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```